# Removing outer borders of calendar from FullCalendar v5

Tags: css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I've been trying to remove the outer borders of my calendar, however the best I've managed is to get all the borders removed (or just horizontal/vertical borders removed).  I only need the outer borders gone (the picture shows what I need gone; the bottom of the calendar isn't in the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXAYP.png). So far, I've spent a long in chrome dev tools trying to figure out exactly where I can do this, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

For reference, I'm using a css file to override the fullcalendar css. I don't think my code is necessary, as I can't even find the right element that would only remove the outer borders.  I am using `border-style: none !important;` I have tried `border: 0px !important;` as well.

The element I am looking for is probably in the cdn for the css aspect of fullcalendarv5: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.css

**EDIT: Code**

cal.html sample:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.css"> -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.js"></script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      events: '/event_view/',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay, listWeek',
      },
      height:'97vh',

    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>

{% load static %}  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'calendar_app/cal.css' %}" type="text/css">

<!-- Event making stuff; not relevant-->
<div class="content-calendar" id="content", name="content-calendar">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

cal.css sample:

```
.fc {
color: green;
}
./*THE ELEMENT I CURRENTLY CANNOT FIND WOULD GO HERE*/ {
border-style: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Provided a minimal example of your working code please

Comment: @AlwaysHelping. I provided some code which shows the fullcalendar being created and the css (color: green proves that I can override the fullcalendar css if I choose to do so).  I don't know how helpful this will be, as my main issue is being able to find the right element inside of https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.css so that I can override it.  Additionally, I need to know if I have the proper css in order to JUST remove the outer borders.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping what would I have to do to remove the top and the left side?  What do you mean by not want any borders at all.  Would you mind providing some code that I can try out? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use border:none on this `.fc-scrollgrid` class to remove border from `top` and `left`

To remove border from the side we need to use [last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudo-class to only remove border-right from `td` using `.fc-scrollgrid td:last-of-type`

> Working Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alwayshelping/hte2pz0f/

Run snippet below to see it working. There are no borders as exactly as you wanted in the picture.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    /*events: '/event_view/',*/  
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay, listWeek',
    },
    height: '97vh',

  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
.fc-scrollgrid {
  border: none !important;
}

.fc-scrollgrid td:last-of-type {
  border-right: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Event making stuff; not relevant-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.css"> -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-calendar" id="content" , name="content-calendar">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this scss styles (hide all out borders)

```scss
.calendar-wrapper {  
  .fc-scrollgrid {
        border-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .fc-scrollgrid td:last-of-type {
        border-right-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .fc-scrollgrid-section.fc-scrollgrid-section-body td[role='presentation'] {
        border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    }
    [role='row']:last-of-type td {
        border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    }
    th[role='presentation'] {
        border-right-color: transparent !important;
    }
}
```